# How to save/restore user search on ng2-smart-table columns if user navigates to a view and then it is returning to the table view?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, nebular, ng2-smart-table

How I can save/restore the user search on ng2-smart-table columns if the user navigates to a view and then it is returning back to the table view (route navigation)? Do you have any ideas?

Thank you

[image]